# Deleting comments error message is wrong

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments

When trying to delete a comment, if there is an error, the message is:

> An error occured during voting.

[image: Error message in action]

This is the same message for an error during voting as well (*no kidding!*). Shouldn't there be a separate message for the deletion error?

Comment: Like most things in the system, you're voting to delete a post.  Posts you create typically have a deletion threshold of 1 unless there are other conditions in apply, but none of those conditions (e.g. accepted, has an upvoted answer in the case of questions) apply for comments.

Comment: @Makoto OP is attempting to delete a comment

Comment: @YvetteColomb: Yes.  I'm acutely aware of that.  The analogy I was going for was that every piece of postable content on Stack Overflow could be considered a post.

Comment: @Makoto wouldn't go with that. They're different objects afaik. Under the database schema they're certainly different entities.